# Div Floats Out of Place

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am displaying 3 div columns all floating left. As windows gets resized to smaller, I want it to get down to 1 column. So far, it's doing that, but when one div gets longer than the other, it all gets out of whack on a normal laptop screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5uLx.png)

The css is:

```css
.kolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 8px;
}

.feed-lists {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

 .feedlists li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 9px;
    text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .kolumn {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="kolumn">
<ul class="feed-lists">
<li class="feed-item"><div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div></li>
<li class="feed-item"><div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div></li>
<li class="feed-item"><div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div></li>
</ul> </div>

 <div class="kolumn">
<ul class="feed-lists">
<li class="feed-item"><div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div></li>
<li class="feed-item"><div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div></li>
<li class="feed-item"><div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div></li>
</ul> </div>
...
```

Any help would be appreciated to get this floats to align left no matter how long are they... am trying to get them in 3 columns... thanks again!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. `float: left` is considered not to be a best practice (anymore). You should check out `display: flex`. Read more about it at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Comment: Check https://getbootstrap.com. This will help you with the design.

Comment: @JakubMuda there is no need for a framework for this simple application. BS would be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly consider using `display: flex` for this instead, since `float` is going the way of the dinosaurs.

To fix what you have, you need to make sure the 1,4,7, etc. element can clear longer elements. Added:

```
.kolumn:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

Removed the media query so you can see it in the snippet window.

```css
.kolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.kolumn:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}

.feed-lists {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.feedlists li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 9px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="kolumn">
  <ul class="feed-lists">
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="kolumn">
  <ul class="feed-lists">
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="kolumn">
  <ul class="feed-lists">
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="kolumn">
  <ul class="feed-lists">
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="kolumn">
  <ul class="feed-lists">
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="kolumn">
  <ul class="feed-lists">
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
    <li class="feed-item">
      <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Here's a `flex` example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.kolumn {
  padding: 8px;
  flex: 1 0 33.3333%;
}


.feed-lists {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.feedlists li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 9px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .kolumn {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="kolumn">
    <ul class="feed-lists">
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="kolumn">
    <ul class="feed-lists">
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="kolumn">
    <ul class="feed-lists">
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="kolumn">
    <ul class="feed-lists">
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="kolumn">
    <ul class="feed-lists">
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="kolumn">
    <ul class="feed-lists">
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feed-item">
        <div class="feed-title"> Title Text Goes here </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I added a `wrap` element with `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` to make sure elements wrap:

Then, each `.kolumn` gets a `flex: 1 0 33.3333%` property - which is shorthand for `flex-grow: 1, flex-shrink: 0, flex-basis: 33.333%` - flex-basis is essentially the flex equivalent to width.

Some really good reading on flex:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried the first example with kolumn.nth-child ... but it didn't quite work... see the link to the screenshot... https://i.ibb.co/Y03D8g9/screenshot.png   Also removing the media css section would not bring the 3 columns to one when viewed on smaller screen (phone)... Let me try with 'wrap'

Comment: @JMStudent I only removed the media query so you could see it in the snippet window - you will still need it in your environment.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't really help, since the snippet I made works. Do you have other code you can share? What are your `.kolumns` wrapped in? Are there other elements in the wrapper? Need more information.

Comment: I added the `media query` back in on the flex example.

Comment: the Wrap worked great!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it to work. If you want, you can accept this answer if it helped.

Comment: The flex I used doesn't work on my iPhone, all three columns show... but when I resize the laptop browser, it works perfectly... There are no other elements used in the code, within the div wrap, i have all div columns.

Comment: What orientation do you have your iPhone? I've tested it and it works as expected